# In iOS, how to move UI elements when a device rotate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In iOS, how to move UI elements (buttons and labels) when a device rotate to landscape mode from portrait mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placing and Moving Views on Rotation (UIView)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104963/placing-and-moving-views-on-rotation-uiview)

Comment: Note that the techniques vary based on which iOS version you're compiling to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways.

In my case, I'm using notification

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(rotated:)
         name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];`

In rotated method

```
-(void) rotated: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        if(UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown==orientation) 
// UI relocation
else if(UIDeviceOrientationPortrait==orientation)
// UI relocation
else if(UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight==orientation)
// UI relocation
else if(UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft==orientation)
// UI relocation
}
```