# How to rearrange views during autorotation in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

A view controller has six rectangular views.  In landscape mode, I want to arrange them 3 columns and 2 rows.  But in portrait mode, I want to arrange them 2 columns and 3 rows.

How do I implement it when iPad rotate between landscape and portrait?

Do I need to have two nib files: one for landscape with 3 columns and 2 rows and the orther for portrait with 2 columns and 3 rows, and swap them during autorotation?

Or something else?  What is the best way to implement this?  Thanks.

Comment: I think this depends upon the specifics of how you want them arranged. In landscape orientation, you might have 1, 2 and 3 on the top row and 4, 5 and 6 on the bottom row. But when you rotate the device _90-degrees **clockwise**,_ are you going to have 1 and 2 on the top row, 3 and 4 on the middle row and 5 and 6 on the bottom row? Or would you have 4 and 1 on the top row, 5 and 2 on the middle row, and 6 and 3 on the bottom row?

Answer (score 1):

You only need 1 nib file. Create IBOutlets for your columns/rows and then manually set them in:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

You will want to make sure to call willRotateToInterfaceOrientation in your viewWillAppear also to make sure that the initial position of your columns/rows are set correctly when you enter the view in landscape mode.

Comment: To make it easier, you can even set the alpha of your the orientation you are not using (ie. portrait) to .5 or .0 so that you can easily see an move things around in the other orientation (the landscape)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to look at UICollectionView. It might work for you. Otherwise, you should look at using autolayout. If you use two nibs you can use UIViewControllers methods such as

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

Alternatively, layoutSubviews is called when the device rotates and you could perform any manipulations there.
I think if the differences are fairly minor then you should not need to use two different Nibs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 xibs, or if you're using layout constraints, you can set it up in portrait mode (in IB), then in code save those constraints to an array in viewDidLoad. In the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method, create new constraints for the landscape orientation and add them to the superview. Check out my answer to this question, [UIView to Ignore Orientation or Stick-To-Bottom Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726461/uiview-to-ignore-orientation-or-stick-to-bottom-container/17729494#17729494) for an example of how I've done this.,