# Change UIViews position when iPhone orientation changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, orientation

I'm trying to change the position of `UIViews` when the iPhone's orientation is changed. It's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104963/placing-and-moving-views-on-rotation-uiview); but instead of 3 `views`, I'll be having 2 `views`. When the iPhone is in portrait mode, I want the `views` to be one on top of the other. When in landscape mode, they should be side by side.

So I tried the following method:

```
willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

But that method is deprecated. What can I do to check when the iPhone's orientation changed?

**Update**

I tried the following: Thanks to @Sean for the guidance!!

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200); // This Works
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    CGFloat viewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat viewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;


    if (size.width >= size.height)
    {
        self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, 272);
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.containerView.frame.size.height, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight - self.containerView.frame.size.height);
        NSLog(@"Portrait Mode");  // Get the NSLog, but frames don't change
    }
    else
    {
        self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight);
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(viewWidth / 2, 0, viewHeight / 2, viewHeight);
        NSLog(@"Landscape Mode");  // Get the NSLog, but frames don't change
    }
}
```

So when I change the frames in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, it works. But when I try changing them in `viewWillTransition...` it doesn't change, but I get the `NSLogs`.

Comment: you need to have two spare view for that. Create two separate views one for portrait and one for landscape.

Comment: Try changing viewWidth = size.width.  Also swap the >= to <= in the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple recommends using the following method:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
   withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

Example:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
   withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    if (size.width >= size.height) {
        // Landscape frames
        self.subviewA.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
        self.subviewB.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    } else {
        // Portrait frames
        self.subviewA.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
        self.subviewB.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Make sure you call the super class method as shown above when implementing this solution.

Comment: I have `auto-layout` applied on all 4 sides. Does that change anything? Meaning, should I remove then re-add `auto-layout`?

Comment: If you're going to be setting the frames programmatically you can get rid of auto-layout

Comment: This gets called before it rotates. How can I get something like this after it rotated. ex. viewDidTransitionToSize. I made that one up. But is there something similar?

Comment: Check out -traitCollectionDidChange in the Apple Docs.  I think that should work

Answer (score 0):

You can check the device orientation by using the following code:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

 if(orientation == 0) //Default orientation 
//UI is in Default (Portrait) -- this is really a just a failsafe. 

 else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
//Do something if the orientation is in Portrait

 else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
// Do something if Left

 else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
//Do something if right
```

You can create two separate views according to your need and present them based on the device orientation.